# how variable = echo php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have JavaScript code
I added it in a php variable
But I want to implement it first and then take the information
Example

```
$nam = "<script>
document.write(5 + 6);
</script>";
```

I want to execute the code and show the results in another variable to put in the database

```
INSERT INTO pro SET nam='$nam'
```

and
I tried to use but failed

```
$nam = echo "<script>
document.write(5 + 6);
</script>";
```

Comment: You can't execute JavaScript inside PHP.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and why?  JavaScript executes in the browser, on the client, long after the PHP has finished executing.  Your `$nam` variable is just a string, nothing more.  And if you're just trying to execute `5 + 6` in PHP then, well, you don't really need JavaScript for that.  PHP can do math.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language.
Javascript is a client-side language.

You can not and should not perform Javascript through text inside a PHP variable.

You can create a Javascript file that calculates 5+6 and sends the result to a PHP page through [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

I suggest you read more about [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) in the link I attached.

- But remember, if you don't need this code to be rendered on the client browser then maybe it would be better to run it in PHP.